# Implement small/medium app bar headlines in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, material-design

[Material 3 specifies](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/guidelines#42364c47-5be5-4fbf-91d1-8eb4e7a95201) a few different text styles to use in app bars, two of which seem to have some special behaviour where the title expands below the app bar if the user scrolls up.

Looking at [Flutter's widget catalogue](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets/material), it seems like this is supported, as the image they use for the app bar card has the title expanded below the app bar, but the documentation does not mention title styles at all.

I did try just setting the titleTextStyle to textTheme.headlineMedium, but that just makes the title text bigger and does not change its behaviour.

Is it possible at all to implement these Material 3 headlines in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with [`SliverAppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html).  `SliverAppBar` embeds `AppBar`, so it comes will all the features from `AppBar` including the latest Material design style.

This is a modified version of one of the examples from the docs:

```dart
class SliverAppBarExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliverAppBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 120,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text(
                'SliverAppBar',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child:
                        Text('$index', textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(5)),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demonstration]